# How to receive sequence of numbers from the user in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am working on my first Dialogflow project and I need to ask the user their PIN number.
If I have one intent ask `For verification, please tell me your PIN number?`, the user may not say `my pin is 1234`.  The user may just say their PIN `1234`.

How do I write the second intent to trigger and receive those numbers?  I assume I have to add entries to the `Training Phrases` section?

Or is there a better way to approach this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the first intent where you are giving response `For verification,
  please tell me your PIN number?`, set some output context like
  `ask-pin`
- Then in the second intent set input context same `ask-pin`, also set output context `ask-pin` and give lifespan `0`
- Give some training phrases like `my pin is 1234` and `1234`
- Set a parameter `$pin` with value `@sys.number`

[image: pin-image]

That's it. We are setting contexts here so that if randomly user is typing 1234 then the chatbot does not get confused that user is giving pin.

Let me know if there is any confusion.